# WYSIWYG editor for Rails with Paperclip Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, wysiwyg, paperclip, attachment-fu

I'm looking for a way of integrating a WYSIWYG editor into my rails app so it will use Paperclip for Image / File uploads.

**What I want is this:** User can use a WYSIWYG field to create some rich text. They can upload an image into this text but the image will be stored nicely in a DB (hopefully using something like Paperclip) instead of just being dumped in a folder on the server.

Can this be done? I've spent a fair while trawling the net for solutions to this problem. The closest I've come is a very handy looking plugin: http://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor

However, the instructions are a bit vague and I got bogged down partway through the implementation.

I don't care what WYSIWYG editor I use, my requirements are very simple. I'm also not totally set on Paperclip so if there's another way (using attachment_fu) I'm happy to consider that too.

Edit:
I'm also happy if I can integrate a WYSIWYG editor with Paperclip and just store the images in the file system. It doesn't have to be uploaded to the DB. Any takers now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered here:

[WYSIWYG image uploads in Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277348/wysiwyg-image-uploads-in-rails-app)

Thanks @[Matchu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107415/matchu)